# Laravel 5.2 extra column in table Users

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Using Laravel 5.2 I added to db table "users" one column "code" and i want filter DB::table results in controller.
I render rows fine in the view. But when i add where clause ->where('code', $codevar) y receive an error message of Auth not found. How

Table Users

```
  id            email                    code           password
  -------+----------------------------+------------+-------------------
  1         admin@admin.com (logged)     007             $2y$10$azWc9kKFU/...
  2         user@user.com                666             $2y$10$azWc9kKFU/...
```

Reports table

```
    code        date            price
    -------+------------------+--------
    007         2016-01-20      $10.20
    666         2016-02-22      $58.00
```

Output

```
    code        month            price
    -------+------------------+--------
    007         01               $10.20
    666         02               $58.00
```

Expected Output

```
    code        month            price
    -------+------------------+--------
    007         01               $10.20
```

**MyController.php**

```
  <?php  
     use DB;
     use Auth;
     namespace LaravelAcl\Authentication\Controllers;
     use Illuminate\Http\Request;
     use LaravelAcl\Library\Form\FormModel;
     use LaravelAcl\Authentication\Models\Permission;
     use LaravelAcl\Authentication\Validators\PermissionValidator;
     use LaravelAcl\Library\Exceptions\JacopoExceptionsInterface;
     use View, Redirect, App, Config;

     class ResumenesController extends Controller
      {

public function getList()
{

    $user      = \Auth::user();
    $codevar   = \Auth::user()->code;/// maybe like this

    $rows= \DB::table('reports')
    ->select('*', \DB::raw('MONTH(date) as month)')
    ->where('code', $codevar)*
    ->orderBy('month','DESC')
    ->paginate(15);

    return View::make('client.report.list',  compact('rows','codevar', 'user'));

}
```

How i retrieve  \Auth::user() or maybe Auth::user()->code.
Only I want obtain these extra column of users table for filter table results...

Any idea to learn please?

Comment: Once you import the class using the use statement at the top of your file, you don't need to reference the Auth class globally. Try to remove the backslash, from the two first lines in the getList method.

Comment: Thanks Chris. if remove that show error  Auth not found or Db not found.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the `auth()->user()` global helper, or the Auth facade but remember that you will always get all of the fields when retrieving the authenticated user.

As Christian Gerdes said in the comment, import the Auth facade at the top and remove the backslash. Do the same for the DB facade.